# Efficiently filtering a MATLAB struct array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, vectorization, slice

Suppose I have a struct array in MATLAB:

```
a= struct('a1',{1,2,3},'a2',{4,5,6})
```

How can I efficiently (i.e. with vectorized code) filter the elements of the struct so that they satisfy some boolean property?

For instance:

1. How would I create a new struct array `b` whose elements are the subset of `a` where **both** `a1` is a multiple of 3 **and** `a2` is a multiple of 3? The expected result is a struct array of size 1 with the element `struct('a1', 3, 'a2', 6)`.
2. How would I create a new struct array `b` whose elements are the subset of `a` where `a1` is odd **or** `a2` is a multiple of 3? The expected result is the following struct array of size 2: `struct('a1', {1,3}, 'a2', {4,6})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem with the mod(...) function and proper use of brackets and referencing. Consider

1. `Mod(x,3)` will return zero if your number is a multiple of 3. `mod(x,2)` will return 1 if x is odd.
2. You can get all your `a1` or `a2` values in a vector by typing `[a.a1]`. Just typing a.a1 gives a mess.
3. You can filter our from your `a` structure by writing `a = a([1 3]);` or by writing `a = a(logical([1 0 1]))` to get the same result.
4. You can use the `&` for  *logical and*  and `|` for logical or ([see here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html)).

Altogether, the following code solves your problem:

```
%% Part 1:
a= struct('a1',{1,2,3},'a2',{4,5,6});
logForA1isMod3 = (mod([a.a1], 3) == 0);
logForA2isMod3 = (mod([a.a2], 3) == 0);

a = a(logForA1isMod3  & logForA2isMod3);

%% Part 2:
a= struct('a1',{1,2,3},'a2',{4,5,6});
logForA1isOdd = (mod([a.a1], 2) == 1);

a = a(logForA1isOdd | logForA2isMod3);
```